# Decimal to binary and binary to decimal conversion

Tags: javascript

I have a problem in converting the decimal to binary values in javascript,After converting the decimal to binary i amm not getting the accurate value please help me solve this issue for example if i convert `72057598599935719` to binary i am getting `100000000000000000000000100001111111010101011011011100000`, and after converting the same binary to decimal  value i am getting `72057598599935710`, please give some suggestion to solve this issue.Here the code i used to convert

```
var dec = this.get('number'),   
    bin = parseInt(dec,10).toString(2)
```

Comment: you may find solution here https://gist.github.com/faisalman/4213592

Comment: Javacript floating point only has 53 bits of precision, your input requires 57 bits.

Comment: but if i want a precised value what i supposed to do

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)